# Connection must be valid and open while inserting records in database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to insert clients details into database but getting this exception

> Connection must be valid and open. at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.Throw(Exception ex) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.CheckState() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior) at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader() at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at book_online.saveClient_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO clientsDetails (clientName, companyAddress, city, contactPersonName, contactNumber1) Values(@clientName, @companyAddress, @city, @contactPersonName, @contactNumber1)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientName", companyName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyAddress", companyAddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", companyCity.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactPersonName", concernPersonName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactNumber1", countryCodeWithNumber);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Did you make sure that your connecting string is right?

Comment: @divinemaniac definitely it's 100% right

Comment: Your command isn't associated with any connection. Just use proper constructor for command to pass connection instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have opened the connection and executed the command as well, but you forgot to **assign the connection to the command**, then only the code works fine as you expected. Strongly recommend you to use using as well. Then the code will looks like the following:

```
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection())
{
    con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString();
    string queryText = "INSERT INTO clientsDetails (clientName, companyAddress, city, contactPersonName, contactNumber1) Values(@clientName, @companyAddress, @city, @contactPersonName, @contactNumber1)";
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(queryText, con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientName", companyName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyAddress", companyAddress.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", companyCity.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactPersonName", concernPersonName.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactNumber1", countryCodeWithNumber);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Command missing connectionstring.**

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection();
con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString();
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO clientsDetails (clientName, companyAddress, city, contactPersonName, contactNumber1) Values(@clientName, @companyAddress, @city, @contactPersonName, @contactNumber1)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientName", companyName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyAddress", companyAddress.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", companyCity.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactPersonName", concernPersonName.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactNumber1", countryCodeWithNumber);
con.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: This code wont compile because of the line : *MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(con);* Due to `The best overloaded method match for 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.MySqlCommand(string)' has some invalid arguments`

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the connection object for your command:

```
cmd.Connection = con;
```

Also, it is better to use a `using` block which automatically close your connection when it exits that block:

```
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection())
{
   con.ConnectionString =
                       ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString();

   MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
   cmd.CommandText = @"INSERT INTO clientsDetails
              (clientName, companyAddress, city, contactPersonName, contactNumber1)
               Values
              (@clientName, @companyAddress, @city, @contactPersonName, @contactNumber1)";

   cmd.Connection = con;
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clientName", companyName.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyAddress", companyAddress.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", companyCity.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactPersonName", concernPersonName.Text);
   cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contactNumber1", countryCodeWithNumber);
   con.Open();
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Just for info, the `using` keyword lets the compile generate a `try...finally` for the enclosed block and calls `Dispose` on the object inside the `using` (`con` in your case) inside the generated finally block. So your connection is guaranteed to be closed in all the cases where finally is guaranteed)

Comment: @Dennis Because it is not mandatory. It does no harm if you don't do it. It just forces the finalizer of that object and has nothing to do with the SQL connection or un-managed resources thing.

Comment: This is not mandatory for connection too. So, why your advice to use `using` for connection ignores that fact, that command also uses un-managed resources?

Comment: @Dennis Disposing a connection closes that SQL connection. Disposing a SQL Command closes what ? It just dispose the object and mark it for garbage collection.

Comment: @user3185569 : *You didn't specify the connection object for your command:*, Connection is not an object of command, its a property of the command.

Comment: Nope. Disposing connection doesn't close physical connection to data source by default. It just returns connection to connection pool, if the pooling isn't turned off. Commands (`IDbCommand` implementations), data readers (`IDataReader` implementations) and transactions (`IDbTransaction` implementations) usually use unmanaged resources too (some sort of handles, ultimately any ADO .NET client code uses unmanaged APIs). They must be disposed too (although they will be finalized as well as connections, if you will forget to call `Dispose`).

Comment: @un-lucky Com'n ! the property is just a method that sets (or gets) the reference for the Connection **object** used by the command. Let's not complicate things here.